# Overlapping of partitions not allowed

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am trying to fix it since 2 days but I simply can't. Things are too confusing. I have Windows that runs good, but I can't install any Linux. GParted shows an error, that overlapping of partitions is not allowed.

Below is the output of: `sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sda`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000001

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   135848514    67924226    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       135852032   219426815    41787392    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       219426814   270635007    25604097    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       270635008   312578047    20971520    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       219426816   238880767     9726976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       238882816   270635007    15876096    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Please tell me how to fix these sectors. Im noob.

Comment: First glance: Your partition tables *are* messed up according to Linux.  GParted will definitely show such errors.  I'd suggest redoing your partitions layout, and manually repartition the drive, but you'll lose data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `/dev/sda2` ends at sector 219,426,815, but `/dev/sda3` begins at sector 219,426,814 -- thus, they overlap. Writing to the very end of `/dev/sda2` will trash `/dev/sda3`, which is extremely dangerous, because `/dev/sda3` is an extended partition, meaning that it's a container for `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6`. Such a write (to the end of `/dev/sda2`) would likely cause those last two partitions to be completely lost.

If I'm reading those values correctly, fixing this will be difficult. The problem is that logical partitions require at least one free sector immediately before they begin. Your `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, and `/dev/sda6` all have such gaps; but `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5` lack such gaps and so must remain primaries. Logical partitions also must be contiguous. Given that you've got five primary or logical partitions, you must convert at least two of them to logical form to make a legal partition table. The only two that can be so converted are `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` -- but it looks like `/dev/sda1` is your Windows boot partition, and converting it to logical form will render it unbootable. (Converting partitions from one form or another can be done with my [FixParts program,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) which is part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu.)

Overall, my first recommendation is to ***BACK UP EVERYTHING ON THAT DISK!*** This is because the disk is in an ***UNSAFE STATE.*** Anything you attempt to do to repair the disk runs the risk of creating even worse problems, so having a backup is critical.

Once you have a backup, one approach to fixing the problem is as follows:

1. Using an Ubuntu live boot and `gdisk`, convert the disk from MBR to GPT format, as described in [the `gdisk` documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) *This will render Windows unbootable!*
2. Using GParted or a tool in an emergency Windows disk, resize your partitions such that there's a short gap before any partition you want to be logical. A single sector is big enough, but with GParted, it's likely to create a ~1MiB gap. That's fine. Since you're trying to install Ubuntu, you might as well open up gaps that are big enough for the Ubuntu installation -- but I wouldn't create new partitions for Ubuntu just yet.
3. Using `gdisk`, do a reverse conversion from GPT to MBR. You'll be able to select which partitions will be primary and which will be logical. Be sure that `/dev/sda1` is primary.
4. Using a Windows emergency disk, re-install the boot loader.
5. Hope it works.

This procedure is very risky; there are any number of things that can go wrong. In the long run, though, it's probably no riskier than leaving it as-is, since your `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6` could disappear at any moment.

Another approach is to back everything up, repartition, and restore everything. It may come to this if you run into serious problems with the procedure I've outlined, so be prepared to do this even if you try my suggested "fix." You could also try a sort of hybrid procedure -- back up `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6`, delete them and `/dev/sda3` (the extended partition that houses them) using `fdisk` in Ubuntu, create new partitions in their place, and then restore the data.

Yet another approach is to convert the disk to GPT form and install an EFI-mode boot loader. This will work only if you have EFI firmware, which became common starting in mid-2011; it most likely won't work on earlier computers. If you've got a newer machine, you can read about the boot mode conversion [here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170306032145/http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) This approach works because GPT doesn't use logical partitions, so converting to GPT removes `/dev/sda3`, leaving only the partitions it contains, and the overlap is gone. (That's also why my earlier procedure converts temporarily to GPT -- your partition layout is legal in GPT, which will enable GParted to resize partitions.)

Comment: Before doing anything back up partition table with sfdisk and backup all your data. `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PTsda.txt` and copy to another device. Then worst case you an restore to where you are now.  There also are advanced ways to manually edit the PTsda.txt file with correct values and restore corrected table.